# How to get more the tow subcollections from a rootcollection

Tags: react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

My database structure so:

|- services (root-collection)
|---- doc1
|-------- reviews (sub-collection 1)
|------------- subdoc1
|------------- subdoc2 ...
|-------- inquires (sub-collection 2)
|------------- subdoc1 ...
My root-collection(services) has two subcollections.
And I wanna get the root-collection with his all subcollections.

I'm using react-redux-firebase & redux-firestore, and connecting to my DB with firestoreConnect.
My code is like that:

```
firestoreConnect((props) => [    
    { collection: 'services', doc: props.match.params.id },
    { collection: 'services', doc: props.match.params.id, subcollections: [{ collection: 'inquiry' }]},
    { collection: 'services', doc: props.match.params.id, subcollections: [{ collection: 'reviews' }]}
  ]),
```

What I expected: I have all data in 'state.firestore.ordered' as Array. 
But always the last query-data(= subcollections : [{ collection: 'reviews' }]) is rewritten over the 'ordered' area. The result was always only one subcollection in there. 
So I just wanna ask 'how to get more than 2 subcollections with firestoreConnect' ? 
I hope anyone gives me some tips what i am doing wrong and missunderstanding !
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You wanna get the root-collection with his all subcollections in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Retrive it like below.

```
let rootRef = db.collection('rootCollection').doc('docId');
   rootRef .getCollections().then(collections => {
   collections.forEach(collection => {
   console.log('Subcollection id:', collection.id);
  });
});
```